# Catalog Grid Custom Filter Function

Tags: attributes, grid, product-list

It is possible to change the catalog grid, of the Magento admin-backend.

That is what I have done. I have added custom attributes to the grid like this:

*First I added a new Attribute to the collection in the `_prepareColection` function*

```
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('ssp_color');
```

*Then I created a new column in the `_prepareColumns` function*

```
    //prepare $colorValues
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'ssp_color');
    $colorValues = array();
    foreach( $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $option ) {
         $colorValues[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
    }

    $this->addColumn('product_color',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Color'),
            'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Colors',
            'index' => 'ssp_color',
            'width' => '100px',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => $colorValues,
    ));
```

Now everything works fine. I have a dropdown where I can select the attribute-value and it then gets filtered as you can see here:

[image: dropdown]

The only problem now is, that some products have multiple values of this attribute but the filter only will return when the value of this attribute is *exactly* the one I was filtering for.

E.g.: I am filtering for orange and want all products which are avaible in orange but can be avaiable in other colors as well. But the filter now is just returning products which are only avaiable in orange.

---

The question now is, did someone had this problem before and how did this one got solved. Is it a setting in the `_prepareColums` function? Or does anybody at least know where the standard filter function is, when there is no `filter_condition_callback` defined for the column?

Comment: The standard filter function is in `\Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_addColumnFilterToCollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$this->addColumn(...)` should get another attribute in the array

```
$this->addColumn('product_color',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Color'),
        'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Renderer_Colors',
        'index' => 'ssp_color',
        'width' => '100px',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'options' => $colorValues,
        'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_colorFilter'),
));
```

This will make the function `_colorFilter()` the filter function for this column.

The function has to be created now:

```
protected function _colorFilter($collection, $column) {
    if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $field = $column->getFilterIndex() ? $column->getFilterIndex() : $column->getIndex();
    $cond = $column->getFilter()->getCondition();
    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter($field, array('finset' => $cond["eq"]));
    return $this;
}
```

This will return all products which have at least one appereance of the attribute you filtered for in them, but can contain even more.